# Error en objeto al intentar llevarlo de javascript a php usando AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Hola estoy haciendo una página en la que el usuario ingresa datos, se forma una tabla con esos datos y los quiero llevar a un php para guardar en MySQL. La tabla la convierto en un array de objetos en javascript, luego mediante ajax intento hacer el POST al archivo PHP. Pero al ejecutarlo me regresa el siguiente error:

**Notice**:  Undefined index: json_mixed in **/php/store.php** on line **4**
 trueArray recibido:console.log('null');

**El código relevante es:**

```js
 <script src="/js/parseTable.js"></script>
            <script>
            
            function parseTableData() {
              var table1 = document.querySelector('#table');
              var output1 = document.querySelector("pre");
              var data1 = parseTable(table1);
              console.table(data1);
        
        
              var table = document.querySelector('#table2');
              var output = document.querySelector("pre");
              var data2 = parseTable(table);
              console.table(data2);
              console.log(typeof (data2));
              
              
              var mixed = new Array();
              var i;
 
                for (i = 1; i < data2.length; i++) { 
                   mixed[i] = [ {
                  "Unidades": data2[i].Unidades,
                  "Producto": data2[i].Producto,
                  "PrecioUnitario": data2[i].PrecioUnitario,
                  "Subtotal": data2[i].SubTotal,
                  "Nota" : data1[1].Nota,
                  "Fecha" : data1[1].Fecha,
                 "PuntoDeVenta" : data1[1].PuntoDeVenta,
                 "Estado" : data1[1].Estado,
                 "Ciudad" : data1[1].Ciudad,
                 "Operacion" : data1[1].Operacion,
                 "FormaDePago" : data1[1].FormaDePago,
                 "Observaciones" : data1[1].Observaciones
                 } ];
                };
                console.log(mixed);
                
                var json_mixed = JSON.stringify(mixed);
                
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open("POST", "php/store.php");
                
                 request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                // Check if the request is compete and was successful
                if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                // Inserting the response from server into an HTML element
                 alert(this.responseText); 
                    }
                };
                
                request.send(json_mixed);
            }
            </script>
```

[image: Esta es la estructura de los objetos que combino para formar "mixed":]

[image: Este es el array combinado antes de pasar por JSON.stringify]

El php es:

```
    <?php      
    echo "dentro";
    include('loginphp.php');  
    $mygetter = $_POST['json_mixed'];
    $data = json_decode($mygetter); //Convert back to array, needed?
    echo "Array recibido:";
    echo "<script>console.log('" . json_encode($data) . "');</script>";
?>
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que envías esas variables por post? El error es muy claro, no existe ese index en la variable post y no existe la variable data. Yo hubiese hecho un json y lo mando en el body de mi consulta y lo recibo por post. Luego envío una respuesta en formato json.

Comment: Depura tu código con `var_dump($_POST);` En ningún momento veo que asignes una clave `obj` a los datos que estás pasando vía Ajax. Por otro lado, te está diciendo claramente que la variable `$data` no existe. ¿De dónde sacas esa variable?

Comment: @gaidyjg si es por vía post. La variable data me equivoqué y solo cambie uno de los nombre de variable, una disculpa, ya corregí ese error. ¿Pudieras detallar un poco más lo del json? Gracias

Comment: @A.Cedano ya depuré con var_dump y con empty($mygetter) veo que la variable llega vacía. $data fue un erro de un cambio en nombre que hice de ultimo momento y no cambie ambos nombres, ya está corregida. Muchas gracias. sobre la clave, (soy muy nuevo en Ajax), tenía entendido que se podía asignar directo al recurso recibido, veo que no ¿cómo asigno el nombre en Ajax? Gracias

Comment: No entiendo a qué te refieres con *asignar directo al recurso recibido*. Sea como sea, si el var_dump no muestra nada significa que por algún motivo la petición Ajax no está funcionando o que los datos que recoges en el cliente para pasarlos al servidor vía Ajax no se están recogiendo adecuadamente. Debes aprender a depurar de ambos lados, en el cliente usa consola.log y activa la consola para verificar lo que estás enviando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás enviando solo una cadena `request.send(json_mixed);`, sin asignarla a variable y, en PHP, al tratar de acceder a `$_POST['json_mixed]` obtienes un error de índice no definido.

Sin modificar el javascript puedes obtener el JSON desde el [flujo de entrada](https://www.php.net/manual/es/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input) con [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
<?php      
$mygetter = file_get_contents("php://input");
// Convertir en objeto para poder acceder a propiedades
$data = json_decode($mygetter);
// Después puedes manipularlo de acuerdo a tus necesidades
```